# Understanding `f: Int => _`

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int)(f: Int => _) = ???
foo: (x: Int)(f: Function1[Int, _])Nothing
```

What is the meaning of `Function1[Int, _]`?

Is `_` an existential? How can I call it?

Answer (score 4):

The `_` is an existential type. In particular, an unbound wildcard. Without any bounds, the compiler is just going to infer it as `Any`, but you can pass any function `Function1[Int, A]`, since the only constraint is that `A <: Any`, and `Function1` is covariant over `A`.

```
scala> def foo(x: Int)(f: Int => _) = f(x)
foo: (x: Int)(f: Function1[Int, _])Any

scala> def f(i: Int): Int = i
f: (i: Int)Int

scala> foo(1)(f)
res2: Any = 1
```

It works, but the result of `f` is `Any`, which makes it not very useful.

You could add an upper-bound to it, and that bound will be inferred:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int)(f: Int => _ <: Int) = f(x)
foo: (x: Int)(f: Function1[Int, _ <: Int])Int

scala> foo(1)(f)
res6: Int = 1
```

I suppose this could be useful in cases where you have a list of functions with the same argument type, but not quite the same return type? i.e. `List[Function1[Int, _]]`. I've never really come across a use for such a thing, though.

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't work though:`scala> foo(1)(x => x) 
<console>:14: error: missing parameter type 
       foo(1)(x => x)`

Comment: Seems as though the type inferencer does not want to expand the anonymous function without any bounds on the existential. The best I could find about this is in [SLS 6.23](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions), but it doesn't explicitly mention existentials.